# Can't Use Live Server ( Visual Studio Code) when folder and file is on my external hard drive

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a pretty old Macbook pro (late 2013) and it was runnning out of storage so I created a new folder and html file on my external hard drive to work on VS Code. When I try to launch the Live Server in my Chrome browser, it simply does not work. I do "cmd L + cmd O" and nothing seems to happen. But when I create a folder and html file on my internal hard drive (Macintosh HD), the Live Server works and I can see my work on my Chrome browser. Why is this and how can I fix it to work on files on my external hard drive.

I tried creating to folders in my external hard drive and despite the folder I used and the location it was allocated in, the Live Server still didn't work. It seems to only work on files in my internal hard drive.